# Parse: Set objects in custom class

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Since it doesn't say in the docs or anywhere online, how do you set objects in custom classes? For example, you make a custom class named Friends, and it has three columns: user (string), added (relation), friends (relation). How would you set user within your app, for example?

Comment: What do you mean set user?

Comment: As in set the string "user"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PFObject subclassing is in the documentation:**
https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses/iOS

You will need to:

1. Create a custom class (see example below)
2. Initialize the class in your AppDelegate.m  (see example below)

Example custom subclass for parse.com, with 'Organization' as the Parse class name:

**Organization.h**

```
//
//  Organization.h
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface Organization : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

@property (retain) NSString *user;
@property (retain) NSString *addressLine1;
@property (retain) NSString *addressState;
@property (retain) NSString *addressZip;
@property (retain) NSString *phone;
@property (retain) NSString *email;
@property (retain) NSString *website;
@property (retain) NSString *contactFirstName;
@property (retain) NSString *contactLastName;
@property (retain) PFFile *logoImage;
@property (retain) NSString *orgDescription;
@property (retain) NSString *name;

@end
```

**Organization.m**

```
#import "Organization.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation Organization

@dynamic addressCity;
@dynamic addressLine1;
@dynamic addressState;
@dynamic addressZip;
@dynamic phone;
@dynamic email;
@dynamic website;
@dynamic contactFirstName;
@dynamic contactLastName;
@dynamic logoImage;
@dynamic orgDescription;
@dynamic name;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"Organization";
}
```

@end

**How to initialize in the AppDelegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    [Organization registerSubclass]; //DO THIS BEFORE YOU START PARSE!
    [Parse setApplicationId:YOUR_ID clientKey:YOUR_KEY];

    ....
```

Comment: What if I already made the class in Parse dashboard? Also, instead of `PFObject`, can my class be a subclass of `UIViewController`?

Comment: If you already made the class in the Parse dashboard, create your `PFObject` subclass to match what you have in Parse. You have to do that anyways; a `PFObject` subclass will only work if you have the same object in the database. // You can't use` UIViewController` as the superclass for a Parse object class; you have to use `PFObject`.

Comment: So I have to make a new class in my xcode project, and I would have to make an instance to the class (Organization for example) in my view controller to access it?

Comment: Correct - simply import the header of your `PFObject` into your .m file for your view controller and go :)

Comment: `+ (NSString *)parseClassName;` is a special function used by Parse's SDK. No need to change that one, but do change the `+ (NSString *)parseClassName` function in the .m file to `return @"Friends";`

Comment: How would I set (for example) "user" string in another class?

Comment: You'll have to be a little more specific - why don't you open a second question so we don't get too off-topic?

Comment: Alright, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039826/parse-how-do-i-set-and-access-objects-of-custom-class