# Parse: How do I set and access objects of custom class?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I've got a custom class in Parse, "Friends". I'd like to access this class in a viewcontroller. After I import "Friends.h", how do I add a new row in that class and set the "user" string for example?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the parse documentation?

Comment: Yes, it says how to make it but not how to access and set it in different classes.

Comment: Is this it? `Friends *friends = [Friends object];
        [friends setObject:@"Into the Groove" forKey:@"trackName"];`

Comment: You looked at: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/stay-classy-objective-c-introducing-native-subclasses-for-parse-objects/ ? You need to show the code you have and be specific about what's missing. Your comment shows you creating a new object and updating a column

Comment: I don't have any code because I don't know how to start to set a variable in a custom class. That was the only code I have, but since it doesn't work; none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the class, you will need to query for objects that match your needs; for instance, all the 'friends' of the current user. You can find out more about that here:

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS

Once you have the returned objects, you can access each one by casting the objects in the returned array at Friends objects, like so:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:@userObject];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
for (Friend *currentFriend in objects) {
    //do something with the currentFriend- display it, etc.
}
```

Comment: Alright, what would I do to set a variable in a custom class?

Comment: ^thats all in the Parse documentation

Comment: Last thing I'm having trouble: Say I set `currentFriend.user = @"username";` inside `//do something with the currentFriend` How do I save it? Does `[currentFriend saveInBackground];` work?